# Access Loggers in Play! Framework

Tags: java, logging, playframework

I was reading about Loggers in Play Framework, when I came across 'Access Loggers'. What is the advantage of Access Loggers over Play.Logger?
I tried to understand from the Play Documentation but could not understand much. Can anyone provide a article or material to understand from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaLogging#Creating-your-own-loggers) is quite clear

> Although it may be tempting to use the default logger everywhere, it’s
>   generally a bad design practice. Creating your own loggers with
>   distinct names allows for flexible configuration, filtering of log
>   output, and pinpointing the source of log messages.
>
> You can create a new logger using the Logger.of factory method with a
>   name argument:
>
> `final Logger.ALogger accessLogger = Logger.of("access");`
>
> A common
>   strategy for logging application events is to use a distinct logger
>   per class using the class name. The logging API supports this with a
>   factory method that takes a class argument:
>
> `final Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(this.getClass());`

So, creating a named logger give you a possibility to configure it differently. You can do it in the `conf\logback.xml`. For example, you can switch off logging of some classes and leave other:

```
<!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
<logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />
```

Comment: Is there any documentations for the configuration of logback.xml which explains the attributes? I have seen the tags like <appender> and <pattern> and also the pattern expression keywords such as %coloredlevel etc... which are not explained clearly.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html

Or you can look in to live examples, like https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/